# Pikachoose datasource with simple style (Slide only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

How do I get rid of the stuff that's showing up at the bottom?
I want to have a simple style slideshow (No controls, no thumb-index, etc. Just the slideshow).

So far, I am able to have Pikachoose create the images dynamically. However, my problems are these:

- I can't get rid of the unwanted items/elements. I want a simple layout like the one in this sample http://www.pikachoose.com/demos/simple/
- I can get Pikachoose to correctly size its background and width: 550px and height: 225

http://jsfiddle.net/2C5YD/4/

I am adding the code for convenience, but It'll help me much more if you edit the jsFiddle

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    ...head code...
    <link type="text/css" href="../../../_api/PikaChoose/4.5.0/styles/simple.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- START: scripts ******************************************************* -->
        <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <!-- Pikachoose -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../_api/PikaChoose/4.5.0/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../_api/PikaChoose/4.5.0/lib/jquery.pikachoose.full.js"></script>
        <!-- Data -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../_temp/StackOverflow/PikaChoose/datasource-js.php"></script>
    <!-- END: scripts ******************************************************* -->

</head>


<body>
<!-- START: content ******************************************************* -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="pikachoose">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: content ******************************************************* -->

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     var $banner = [{"image":"_img/home/banner/banner_01.jpg","caption":"My caption","link":"#","title":"It's a title"}...and so on...];         

    $(".pikachoose").PikaChoose( {data:$banner, speed: 4000, animationSpeed: 1500} );
} );
```

Comment: You can set, $(".pikachoose").PikaChoose( {data:$banner, speed: 4000, animationSpeed: 1500,showCaption:false,autoPlay:true}); all options are mentioned at http://www.pikachoose.com/versions/

Comment: @miki-shah thanks for the comment, but I am not sure you payed attention to my question. Also, your suggestion did not fix any of my problems. Besides, the sample link ("simple layout": http://www.pikachoose.com/demos/simple/) I provided does includes captions.

Comment: hi, did you solve your problem? I am trying to disable navigation (next and prev arrows) which appears on hover, but cannot find solution, could you give me any hint?

Comment: @johannesmatevosyan no one offered an answer and I could not find a solution myself =( ... I decided that I'd be better off choosing a different slider with more support like `jquery-cycle 2` or `fancybox`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I solved the problem by re-writing core css code.